# How to URL encode a dynamic email variable in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

i just wanna know if there is a way to url encode an dynamic email variable in postman?
basically i want random names in all parts of the email for my collection run. For example test1@abc.com , ybc@asd.com.(which can be solved by using the email variable provided by postman) However, i also need to url encode that email so it will look something like this

test1%40abc.com

please let me know if this can be achieved with JS code snippet or any other easier method, Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your request's preRequest script:
`pm.environment.set("randomEncodedEmail", encodeURIComponent(pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomEmail}}')));` to generate an encoded random email address.

Then you can just use {{randomEncodedEmail}} in your request to use it.